# Qt SDK download for MingW

Tags: qt, sdk

I´m looking for Qt SDK for windows that uses MingW as the compiler. Unfortunately, on the official download sites, I can only find the one that uses MSVC. Or just the library instead of the whole SDK.

Can anybody tell me where I can find the version I am looking for, or explain what I should do if I download QT library, QT creator and MingW seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find pre-release builds using MinGW 4.7.
http://releases.qt-project.org/digia/5.0.1/latest/

They work well with the MinGW builds distributed here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

The Qt builds come with Qt Creator, so you can install it and should be good to go after setting up your kits.

Answer (score 1):

You can find binaries here:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23002/
But then you ought to reconfigure installation manual or you may use [this](http://www.runfastsoft.com/) utility.
Some guy from Digia [promised](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/12/19/qt-5-0/) MinGW builds by the end of January, so you can wait instead.